# Не выходит передать переменную в функции. JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, переменные

```
function mapArray(...a){
    
    arr = a ;
    let arr2 = arr.map(function(num) {
        return num +3;
      });

}   
mapArray([2,5,8])
```

Есть функция которую описал выше, и у меня проблема когда я пытаюсь получить num+3 для каждого элемент(чтоб было 5,8,11) не получаю данного результата. Но код ниже все выводит что мне нужно.

```
function mapArray(){
    
    arr = [2,5,8]  ;
    let arr2 = arr.map(function(num) {
        return num +3;
      });

}   
mapArray()
```

Подскажите что делаю не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашу функцию можно записать вот так:

```
function mapArray(a){  
  return a.map((num) => num + 3);
}   

mapArray([2,5,8])
```

У вас в коде две ошибки - функция `mapArray` ничего не возвращает. Необходимо добавить `return`.
И так же вы используете оператор расширения  `...` который не нужен, в случае если вы и так передаете массив. Он подошел бы в случае если вы передавали отдельно 3 аргумента, например вот так:

```
mapArray(2,5,8)
```

Так же я заменил синтаксис метода `map` на стандарт ES6 с использование стрелочной функции.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы функция что-то возвращала - нужно добавить в ней `return`, что буквально означает "вернуть". Вот и возвращаем уже новый массив.

Выводить ничего не будет, т.к. Вы собственно и не выводите. Оберните полученное значение из функции в `console.log`.

```js
function mapArray(...arr) { // PS. В этом случае я функцию назвал бы как-то по-другому (нп. mapValues), т.е. в mapArray логично бы было принимать массив
  return arr.map(function(num) {
    return num + 3;
  });
}

console.log(mapArray(2, 5, 8));
```